# Are there new Task object created when we chain the ContinueWith calls?

Tags: c#, async-await, task, compiler-optimization, value-type

Consider a situation when the method returns a chain of tasks, like this one(I was working mainly with .net 3.5, so the example uses ContinueWith, but the question is the same for `await`):

```
 static Task UnwrappedTask()
    {
        Task<Task> t = TestStr().ContinueWith( (
            return  GetTaskFromString(s).ContinueWith(
                // returns a task 
            });
        });
        return t.Unwrap();
    }

    static async Task GetTaskFromString(string str)
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
    }

    static async Task<string> TestStr()
    {
        await Task.Delay(3000);
        return "res";
    }
```

Is there a new Task object created every time we return from `ContinueWith()`, or does the compiler reuse the instance somehow? I am interested in how the Value type Task.Result behaves in this scenario: is it copied all those times, or does the wrapper Task class provide an efficient way of transporting it to the outermost method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ContinueWith` will *always* create a new task.  It can't possibly do anything else.  The whole design of the method is that `ContinueWith` takes an existing `Task`, executes some arbitrary method after it has finished, and produces a new result.  The result of `ContinueWith` isn't ever going to be identical to the task it is a continuation of, so it can't just re-use it.  It is, by design, not *mutating* the task it's adding a continuation to (at least in any externally visible way, technically storing the continuations to fire is an internal mutation of the Task).